# Different versions of Heine-Borel theorem (Math subject GRE exam 0568 Q.62)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, compactness

The question and its answer is in the following 2 pictures, I do not understand why also II is right, I do not understand the statement "we will prove it using the other direction of Heine-Borel theorem ", I know that the statement of the Heine-Borel theorem is:

> A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is compact iff $E$ is closed and bounded.

So what do the writer mean by saying the other direction? may be he mean the contrapositive of the theorem? but the theorem did not speak about real valued functions.

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Thanks!!

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: In I he uses compact implies closed and bounded; in II he uses closed and bounded implies compact.

Comment: The Heine Borel theorem says that a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed and bounded if and only if it is compact.  One direction is : if it is compact, then it is closed and bounded. The "other" direction is : if it is closed and bounded, it is compact. The Heine Borel theorem is like a 2 in 1 theorem, in that it says that two properties are equivalent in a certain case. The directions of this two in one theorem are the facts that one property implies the other.

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem is something about open covers.  If your definition of "compact" is the one about open covers, then your formulation is OK, although that definition dates from much later than the Heine-Borel theorem itself.

Comment: Historical note: Heine proved at least the 1-dimensional case well before Borel, who re-discovered it.  Occurances like that were at one time not so rare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "the other direction", the writer means the contraposition.
In fact, Heine-Borel's theorem states that for any subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have :
$$\text{$K$ is compact} \iff \text{$K$ is bounded and closed}$$

We'll write, just as a notation :
$$II(K) \overset{def}{\iff} \text{Every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded}$$

The writer first shows that $\lnot(\text{$K$ is bounded}) \implies \lnot(II(K))$, which is equivalent to :
$$II(K) \implies \text{$K$ is bounded}$$

Then, the writer shows that $\lnot(\text{$K$ is closed}) \implies \lnot(II(K))$, which, again, is equivalent to :
$$II(K) \implies \text{$K$ is closed}$$

From these two statements, we obtain :
$$II(K) \implies \text{$K$ is compact}$$

Which is exactly II's statement !

Comment: In the seventh line I think you mean $II(K)$ is compact.....right?

Comment: Nope ! Sorry if it's unclear : I just defined the mathematical sentece $II(K)$ to be a shortcut for saying "Every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded". $II(K)$ cannot be compact because it isn't a set : it's a predicate, true or false according to the fact that it is true or false that every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded. And I have chosen to write $II$ just because it is the second proposition of your exercise, it really has no mathematical meaning by itself. Hope it's clear now !

Comment: But I do not understand also why if $K$ is unbounded then there exist a continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ that is unbounded? and also  I do not understand  why if $K$ is not closed then there exist a continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ that is unbounded?

Comment: Firstly : let's show that $\lnot \text{$K$ is bounded} \implies \lnot (II(K))$.

We suppose $K$ unbounded, which means :
$$\forall M > 0, \exists x, y \in K, \|x - y\| > M$$
We transform the definition in $M$ with one in $n$ :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x_n, y_n \in K, \|x_n\| + \|y_n\| \geq \|x_n - y_n\| > n$$

If both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are bounded, then $(x_n + y_n)$ is bounded too, which is absurd, so $(x_n)$ or $(y_n)$ is unbounded. Let's say it's $(x_n)$.
$\|.\|$ is continuous and $\|x_n\| \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} +\infty$, which leads to $\lnot(II(K))$

Comment: Secondly : $\lnot(\text{$K$ is closed}) \implies \lnot(II(K))$.

we suppose $K$ not closed, so $\exists (x_n) \in K^{\mathbb{N}}$ such as $x_n \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} l \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$. We define

$$f : \begin{matrix}
K & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}_+ \\
x & \longmapsto & \frac{1}{\|x - l\|}
\end{matrix}$$

$f$ is continuous because $\|.\|$ and $\cdot^{-1}$ are. Moreover, $\|x - l\| \underset{x \to l}{\longrightarrow} 0$, so $f(x) \underset{x \to l}{\longrightarrow} +\infty$ and $f$ is unbounded, which leads to $\lnot(II(k))$.
Is it clear that time ?